# Configuration issue in HBase : Error thrown

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I am new to Hadoop. I am running HBase 0.94.6-cdh4.4.0 (Pseudo Distributed mode). When I am trying to run `list` command in hbase . It is throwing the following error :

```
bash-4.1$ hbase shell
14/03/05 08:44:15 WARN conf.Configuration: hadoop.native.lib is deprecated. Instead, use        io.native.lib.available
HBase Shell; enter 'help<RETURN>' for list of supported commands.
Type "exit<RETURN>" to leave the HBase Shell
Version 0.94.6-cdh4.4.0, rUnknown, Tue Sep  3 20:09:51 PDT 2013

hbase(main):001:0> list
TABLE                                                                                                                                                                   
14/03/05 08:44:27 ERROR client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: Check the value configured in 'zookeeper.znode.parent'. There could be a mismatch with the one configured in the master.
14/03/05 08:44:28 ERROR client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: Check the value configured in 'zookeeper.znode.parent'. There could be a mismatch with the one configured in the master.
14/03/05 08:44:29 ERROR client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: Check the value configured in 'zookeeper.znode.parent'. There could be a mismatch with the one configured in the master.
14/03/05 08:44:31 ERROR client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: Check the value configured in 'zookeeper.znode.parent'. There could be a mismatch with the one configured in the master.
14/03/05 08:44:33 ERROR client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: Check the value configured in 'zookeeper.znode.parent'. There could be a mismatch with the one configured in the master.
14/03/05 08:44:37 ERROR client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: Check the value configured in 'zookeeper.znode.parent'. There could be a mismatch with the one configured in the master.
14/03/05 08:44:41 ERROR client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: Check the value configured in 'zookeeper.znode.parent'. There could be a mismatch with the one configured in the master.

ERROR: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MasterNotRunningException: Retried 7 times
```

Here is some help for this command:

```
List all tables in hbase. Optional regular expression parameter could
be used to filter the output. Examples:

  hbase> list
  hbase> list 'abc.*'
```

Comment: Can you check through the `jps` command what processes are being run. I believe HMaster is not running.

Comment: Indeed! 'MasterNotRunningException' is quite explicit. What is the result for "jps -lvmV | grep HMaster"?